# Copy paste a specific range in every worksheet and paste that range into separate workbooks to be saved in a single folder

Tags: excel, vba

1. this code works for copying all the data in the sheet into separate workbooks, I want to copy only a specific area from each sheet to separate workbooks.
2. Before the IF statement, I put the following statement under the xWs.Copy, I specified the range as xWs.Range("E2:G15").Copy, the code doesn't work. Kindly help me to solve or give me any hints. I am new to VBA. thank you very much

   ```
   Sub SplitWorkbook()

   Dim FileExtStr As String 
   Dim FileFormatNum As Long 
   Dim xWs As Worksheet 
   Dim xWb As Workbook 
   Dim FolderName As String

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set xWb = Application.ThisWorkbook
   DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
   FolderName = xWb.Path & "\" & xWb.Name & " " & DateString
   MkDir FolderName

       For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
          xWs.Copy
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
           FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
               Else
               Select Case xWb.FileFormat
               Case 51:
                 FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
               Case 52:
                 If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                 FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
               Else
                 FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
               End If
           Case 56:
               FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
           Case Else:
               FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
     End If
      xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & FileExtStr
       Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
      Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
   Next
   MsgBox "You can find the files in " & FolderName
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Could you please update the code to reflect `xWs.Range("E2:G15").Copy` and any other changes you've made?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you loop through the sheet, you can add a workbook, then copy and paste the range to the new workbook.save and close the new workbook.

This sample shows how to do that.

I didn't mess with the save part of your code, I assume that is working for you.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook, bk As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh
            Set bk = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
            .Range("E2:G15").Copy bk.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
            bk.SaveAs "C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Temp\" & sh.Name & ".xlsx"
            bk.Close
        End With
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you did with above code is, you saved your existing Excel to new path. You did copy but you never paste. If you wanted to copy to new workbook you should open new workbook and then you could paste to this workbook:

```
'open new workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

Or you could delete from existing Excel what you do not want and save it to new path as you did here.

You can check how to copy paste on site
https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/

Comment: `sheet1.copy` creates a new workbook with just that copied sheet